# SQL Case of IF?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
   SELECT f.user_id, f.item_id, f.status, f.shipped,
     CASE
      WHEN f.status = 0 THEN UPDATE f SET f.status = 1 WHERE f.user_id = 1 AND f.item_id = 1
      WHEN f.status = 1 THEN UPDATE f SET f.status = 0 WHERE f.user_id = 1 AND f.item_id = 1
      ELSE 'ERROR'
    END CASE
   FROM business AS f;
```

Hi, I want to update the status of an item based on its value ( 0 or 1). I still got syntax error. Am I using the right conditional statements or should I use IF()? If so, how can I put another query inside the IF()?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read the documentation for *case expressions*, you need to write an *update* query.

Comment: so basically for `user_id` = 1 and `item_id` = 1, you want to flip the `status` from 1 to 0 and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the actual data in the table, then use an [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) statement, not a `SELECT` statement:

```
UPDATE business
SET status = 
        CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 0 
             WHEN status = 0 THEN 1
             ELSE -1 --Likely this has to be numeric since you are setting a numeric column, right? 
             END
WHERE user_id = 1 AND item_id = 1;
```

Running this will update your `business` table for the record(s) where `user_id = 1` and `item_id=1` switching the values of `status` unless the current status value isn't `1` or `0`, in which case it will set `status` to `-1`. Note that the string `'error'` can't be used a value unless this column is a `varchar` or similar string-type column.

Comment: and what if i want to insert a new row into the table if item_id=NOT EXIST or update it to 1 if item_id=0?

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple SQL query:

```
UPDATE business b
SET b.status = CASE WHEN b.status = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
WHERE b.user_id = 1 AND b.item_id = 1;

SELECT * FROM  business;
```